Undefined Symbol Referenced In Linker Script
I am trying to modify the linker script for my project based on an Infineon PSoC4 MAX to explicitly place the ISR vector table in a specific location. However, the IDE is complaining that __VECTOR_TABLE is an undefined symbol. But it is defined in the startup file for my MPN:
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Exception / Interrupt Vector table
*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


extern const cy_israddress __VECTOR_TABLE[CY_VECTOR_TABLE_SIZE];


const cy_israddress __VECTOR_TABLE[CY_VECTOR_TABLE_SIZE] __VECTOR_TABLE_ATTRIBUTE = {


 (cy_israddress)(&__INITIAL_SP), /* Initial Stack Pointer */

The line in the linker script:
.text appl_start :
{

CREATE_OBJECT_SYMBOLS


PROVIDE(__cy_interrupt_vector = __VECTOR_TABLE);

Error message:
modustoolbox/tools_3.2/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe:./bsps/TARGET_PSoC4_MAX/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/Application_linker.ld:142: undefined symbol `__VECTOR_TABLE' referenced in expression
Is this because VECTOR_TABLE is reserved for internal compiler use?

Why don't you modify the address of section where VECTOR_TABLE is located?

@Stas Simonov - but I'd do that with the linker script, right?

I suppose. I had experience of such relocation.

Did you look into the symbol table of the compiled module to check that the symbol is there, and what it is exactly? Some compilers add underscore characters as a prefix.

Please [edit] your question to provide a [mre]. A quick check with godbolt did not reveal any symbol problem.
